# show Imageview at distance 30% from top of the screen android

Tags: android, imageview, padding

I have a splash screen which displays the app logo in `Imageview` at center of the screen .

I need to show the `imageview` at a distance 30% from the top of the screen , so that the 70% of the screen at bottom looks empty

I have idea about padding , but don't know how to use %( percentage ) with this condition

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_splashlogo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="SplashImage"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo_splash" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code that you can use putting the image in the linear layout and then use this code

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
Button okButton=new Button(this);
okButton.setText("some text");
ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams);
```

Comment: I already have linear layout .in xml .. Can I use it or need to create in java code ?

Comment: u need to use this code in the desire java file linked with the Splash screen view

Comment: or one more thing first try adding and invisiable view on the top on the image and set image after that giving the 0.3 weight to the top in visiable image by android:visibility="invisible"and android:weight="0.30" to the view on top of your splash image

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/app_splash" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.30"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_splashlogo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="SplashImage"
            android:layout_margin="20dip"
            android:src="@drawable/app_logo_splash" />


        </LinearLayout>

      <View 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0.70"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u do a favour .. I posted a question , but still nobody replied it ... can u help in this case ..